# How to read a file, line by line, also the content in every line is separated with a blank space and write it in a new file

Tags: c++

For example, i read a file with:

```
Cat Dog Monkey 1234
A,A #$%&  No
```

And i need save every word in another (yes another) file like:

```
word 1: cat
word 2: Dog
word 3: Money
word 4: 1234

word 1: A,A 
word 2: #$%& 
word 3: 
word 4: No
```

I just have the basic code of ofstream from examples so if anyone can help me with that, would be great. Also there is a way to save these words and compare if start with A number, letter, symbol or have comas? (,).
I know is a long request so every piece of info will be appreciated (>n<)

Comment: What have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is rather straigthtforward.

First, we open the files and check, if that worked. The we read the source file line by line in a `for`-loop and use `std::getline` to extract a complete line.

For easier processing and usage of the `std::istream_iterator`, we then put the line into a `std::istringstream`.

For transforming the data from the source format to the destination format, we will use the (for this purpose dedicated function `std::transform`.

That's basically it,

Please see the below simple and short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string sourceFileName{ "source.txt" };
const std::string resultFileName{ "result.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceStream(sourceFileName); sourceStream) {

        // open destination file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream resultStream(resultFileName); resultStream) {

            // Read the source file line by line
            for (std::string line{}; std::getline(sourceStream, line); ) {

                // Put the just read file into a istringstream for easier processing
                std::istringstream iss(line);

                // Read every sub-string in the istringstream and convert it to the expected result, using a stateful Lambda
                std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(resultStream, "\n"),
                    [i = 1U](const std::string& s) mutable { return "word " + std::to_string(i) + " " + s; });
                resultStream << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file '" << sourceFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open result file '" << resultFileName << "'\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**

I just noted that you want to split 2 consecutive spaces as well. For that I created a split function. The function will then look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

const std::string sourceFileName{ "r:\\source.txt" };
const std::string resultFileName{ "r:\\result.txt" };

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& s) {

    // Result as vector of string
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;

    // Start searching at the beginning
    size_t startPos{ 0U };

    // Search all spaces
    for  (size_t foundPos{ 0U }; (foundPos = s.find(' ', startPos)) != std::string::npos; ) {

        // And store the sub string before the found space
        splitted.push_back(s.substr(startPos, foundPos - startPos));
        startPos = foundPos+1;
    }
    // At the end of the string there is no space. So add last sub-string
    splitted.push_back(s.substr(startPos));
    return splitted;
}


int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceStream(sourceFileName); sourceStream) {

        // open destination file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream resultStream(resultFileName); resultStream) {

            // Read the source file line by line
            for (std::string line{}; std::getline(sourceStream, line); ) {

                std::vector vs = split(line);

                // Read every sub-string  and convert it to the expected result, using a stateful Lambda
                std::transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(resultStream, "\n"),
                    [i = 1U](const std::string& s) mutable { return "word " + std::to_string(i) + " " + s; });
                resultStream << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file '" << sourceFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open result file '" << resultFileName << "'\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to go in the direction of hardcore C++, you may use a regex and the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. This thing has been made for splitting strings and could be used as well.

This leads to an elegant C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

const std::string sourceFileName{ "r:\\source.txt" };
const std::string resultFileName{ "r:\\result.txt" };

const std::regex re{R"([ ]{1})"};

int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceStream(sourceFileName); sourceStream) {

        // open destination file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream resultStream(resultFileName); resultStream) {

            // Read the source file line by line
            for (std::string line{}; std::getline(sourceStream, line); ) {

                // Read every sub-string  and convert it to the expected result, using a stateful Lambda
                std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(resultStream, "\n"),
                    [i = 1U](const std::string& s) mutable { return "word " + std::to_string(i) + " " + s; });

                resultStream << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file '" << sourceFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open result file '" << resultFileName << "'\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will read this thoughtful and if i fail, i will edit the post with the result :D